# If Statement, do function, say statement

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple if statement. I have data like this

```
Number  Description        Type
1       Snow in road       "weather"
2       Ice on Roof        "Weather"
3       Dog bite           "Not Classified"
```

Basically trying to do this:

```
if(data$type == "Not Classified") {sapply(data$description, colcheck)} else "Not Classified"
```

The desired result would be for the function that I have stated previously in my code to run on row 3, the `"Not Classified"` row. For some reason, I keep getting the same error:

```
"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".
```

`colcheck` is a function created previously. I have tried `IfElse`, taking out the `else` at the end, and adding a `do` in front of the function, but they aren't working. I am trying to filter the data to only use the function on the rows where `type == "Not classified"`. Thank you

Comment: Maybe: `data$newColumn <- ifelse(data$type == "Not Classified", colcheck(data$description), "Not Classified")`

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data$type` is a vector of length > 1. The `==` operator compares a single value only and when you pass it a vector, it takes only the first value, rather than failing.

What you want to do is use `apply` or `dplyr::mutate` to apply the test to each element of `data$type`:

```
data <- data.frame('Number' = c(1,2,3),
                   'Description' = c('Snow in road', 'Ice on Roof', 'Dog bite'),
                   'Type' = c('weather', 'Weather', 'Not Classified'))

  Number  Description           Type
1      1 Snow in road        weather
2      2  Ice on Roof        Weather
3      3     Dog bite Not Classified
```

Example function for `colcheck`:

```
colcheck <- function(x) return(paste0('x',x,'x'))
```

Using base `apply`:

```
apply(data, 1, function(row) {
    if (row['Type'] == 'Not Classified') {
        return(colcheck(row['Description']))
    } else {
        return(row['Description'])
    }
})

[1] "Snow in road" "Ice on Roof"  "xDog bitex"
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate('colcheck' = if_else(Type == 'Not Classified',
                                colcheck(Description),
                                paste(Description)))

  Number  Description           Type     colcheck
1      1 Snow in road        weather Snow in road
2      2  Ice on Roof        Weather  Ice on Roof
3      3     Dog bite Not Classified   xDog bitex
```

Comment: I used the apply and it is working but it is working on everything. It is changing all the already classified rows to "Not Classified" if they are not "Not Classfied".

Comment: What do you want it to do? In the example you gave, if `type == 'Not Classified'` then if runs `colcheck` and returns the result. Otherwise, it returns the string `'Not Classified'`. That's what this does. What do you want it to do if `type != 'Not Classified'`?

Comment: I want it to do nothing to those rows. Sorry, I want it to return "Not Classified" if the function returns false. I tried to make the return "data$colcheck" (per your example), but it is returning something odd.

Comment: Then just change what it returns if `data$type == 'Not Classified'` is `FALSE`. I've changed it above so in that case, it just returns the value of the `description` column unchanged.

Comment: I was referring to the data frame  you created above with the colcheck column. I am putting in the dplyr function and I am still getting the same error, "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: I tried it again with the exact data you used in your example and it seems to work fine. Try restarting R (unexpected objects lurking in the global environment are a common cause of R problems), make sure you have `dplyr` installed and loaded, and make sure capitalization matches (R is case sensitive)

Comment: @Reagan Did you ever solve your problem? If you found a different solution, you can post that as your own answer,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using functions, I just did one large ifelse statement for each classification. For example,

```
ifelse(data$type = grepl('Snow| Ice | Rain',data$description, ignore.case = TRUE)),"Weather","Not Classified")
```

And another for Nonweather, creating a new column of their results.

```
ifelse(data$type1 = grepl('Dog Bite| Stinky House| Mice Infestation',data$description, ignore.case = TRUE)),'Non-Weather',"Not Classified")
```

And then, since non-weather classification is dependent on the weather classification, I made this simple if statement to accept whatever the weather result was, and then move on to non-weather words, all in a new column adjacent to the others.

```
data$Type2<-ifelse(data$Type == "Weather", 
"Weather",data$Type1)
```

And then I deleted "Type1" and "Type" column and changed the name of "type 2" to just "Type" to keep the results I wanted.

It may be lengthy or sloppy, but it did the trick!